# Key-binding doesn't work as expected, "nnoremap <leader>td $F)i, args2<ESC>"

Tags: key-bindings

```
nnoremap <leader>td $F)i, args2<ESC>
```

---

```
# base string
test ----> (args1)

# expected string after <leader>td
test ----> (args1, args2)

# real result string 
test ----> (args1)
```

The above are the `key-map` and what I expect with the `key-map`. However, the result is that the cursor is stopped the end of the string not entering `insert mode`. When I simulate the `key-map`, typing keys in the `<leader>td` by hand, it works.

In addition, The more wired thing is the below. After appending a character at the end of the string, It works as expected.

```
# base string, I append ':' character at the end of the string
test ----> (args1):

# real result string, it works !!!?
test ----> (args1, args2):
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `:h map-error`:

```
                                                        *map-error*
Note that when an error is encountered (that causes an error message or beep)
the rest of the mapping is not executed.  This is Vi-compatible.
```

In your mapping, if the `F` command fails to find a closing parenthesis, Vim will stop processing the rest of the `{rhs}`.

If you want Vim to ignore a possible error, you could use the `:silent` command, followed by the `!` argument. From `:h :sil`:

```
When [!] is added, error messages will also be
skipped, and commands and mappings will not be aborted
when an error is detected.
```

Here's how you could rewrite your mapping, using the `:normal` command to type the keys from the command line, prefixed by `:silent` to ignore any error:

```
nno  <silent>  <leader>td  :<c-u>sil! norm! $F)i, args2<cr>
```